# Check extensions vendor

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, development, plugin

Is there a way to check if in a Joomla! installation there are extensions from a specific vendor?
In a plugin that i have i need to apply different procedures if a specific vendor products are present. Maybe querying db for author name?
Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

The author is saved in the `manifest_cache` in the `#__extensions` table.
So you need to query the db to get that fields and the json_decode the values (or pass it into JRegistry) and look for the author.

Comment: Could you please take a look into my answer? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on Bakual answer i came up with this code. This will only search for 'component' and 'template' type extensions.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$fields = array(
    $db->quoteName('extension_id'),
    $db->quoteName('manifest_cache')
);

$query->select($fields)->from($db->quoteName('#__extensions'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$vendors = $db->loadObjectList();

$extensions = array();

foreach($vendors as $vendor)
{
    $temp = new JRegistry;
    $temp->loadString($vendor->manifest_cache, 'JSON');

    $excList = array('joomla'); //This array will contain a extension list

    foreach($excList as $ext)
    {
        if ((stripos($temp->get('author'), $ext) !== false) && $temp->get('type') == 'component' || (stripos($temp->get('author'), $ext) !== false) && $temp->get('type') == 'template')
        {
            $extensions[] = array(
                'id'   => $vendor->extension_id,
                'type' => $temp->get('type'),
                'name' => $temp->get('name')
            );
        }
    }
}
```

made a test with 'joomla' as vendor name and generates a array like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [type] => component
        [name] => com_mailto
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [type] => component
        [name] => com_wrapper
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [type] => component
        [name] => com_admin
    )

...

[29] => Array
    (
        [id] => 502
        [type] => template
        [name] => bluestork
    )

[30] => Array
    (
        [id] => 10067
        [type] => component
        [name] => com_joomlaupdate
    )
)
```